# Caesar Cipher, in c, from existing file

Tags: c, encryption

I am trying to do a decryption using Caesar Cipher, from a file. The file is a .txt, the program is supposed to read the file, decrypt it (4-letter alphabetic shift), and then print the decrypted message. I am having trouble beginning, all I have so far is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

double val;
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("encrypted.txt", "r"); /* Opens encrypted.txt for reading */
fscanf(fp, "%lf", &val);

}
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.. also I prefer to NOT use loops on this. Thanks!

Comment: What is the specific problem here?

Comment: You are reading a number from the file, is that really what you want to do?

Comment: The file contains text, I am trying to read in that text, perform a 4-letter alphabetic shift on each of the characters in the text file, then display that result. Should I read in as a string?

Comment: Why would you want to avoid loops? Is it some kind of assignment, proof of concept or are you just learning C and you don't master loops yet?

Comment: I am learning c currently. I've done a few loops, only in this case my professor advises against using loops unless we've programmed with loops prior to the course (I'm ~4 weeks in, we've not covered them yet)

Comment: You didn't cover loops, but already learned how to access files? Bizarre teaching decision IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Since you perform the "decryption" per char, you can use getc(fp) inside a loop (I fail to see how you plan to avoid loops in this case...), and modify the result as you want.

I'm not sure what you mean by 4-letter shift, but I presume you meant something like -

```
c += 4;
if (c > 'z' && c <= 'z' + 4)
    c = c -'z' + 'a';
else if (c > 'Z' && c <= 'Z' + 4)
    c = c -'Z' + 'A';
```

or

```
c = (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') ? ((c + 4 - 'a') % ('z'-'a')) + 'a' : ((c + 4 - 'A') % ('Z'-'A')) + 'A'
```

These can be simplified further (for e.g. - since 'z' - 'a' == 'Z' -'A'), you can even convert these to constants, although the compiler will probably do that for you anyway. I left it at that for better readability

Comment: For the 4-letter shift, I meant that a letter input, say 'A', would decrypt as alphabetically moving 4 letters over, so A..b,c,d,..E and 'E' would be the output. Sorry to confuse you

Comment: That's what this code should do, assuming you want it to wrap around ('z'->'d', ..)